# Connection closing for singleton connection

Tags: java

I'm trying to use many object with a singleton connection,the problem I face is when to close the connection. here is my main class Car

```
public class Car{
    DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;

    public void close() throws SQLException {
        databaseHelper.close();
    }
}

public class DatabaseHelper {

    private static DatabaseHelper instance = null;
    private Connection connection;
    private ResultSet resultSet;
    private PreparedStatement preparedStatement;

    public static DatabaseHelper getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new DatabaseHelper();
        }
        return instance;
    }
    void close() throws SQLException {
        //close code
    }
}
```

The problem I face is when to close the singleton connection.Ofcourse it has to be closed when no longer any Car object invokes a method from the databaseHelper which invokes methods which return value from the database.But I have no rule for now saying when to close the singleton connection(for example if some event happens) so is it ok,just to call close method on the last Car object when no retrieving is done and is there better design?

Comment: Btw a Car having a close method  - doesn't seem to be right.

Comment: So any suggestions to change the design with the same requirements?

Comment: It depends on when you *are done* with your database access. If it is a long-running process like a web application, then I don't think you need to close it (unless you are performing a shutdown sort of thing)

Comment: Sounds like your DatabaseHelper is not a singleton. Instead, you want to keep track of number of instances and close the underlying connection when they have ALL been closed.